# Trying to set up 3 hearts to decrease when the player is hit but can only get one to work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Below is my code. I've connected hearts one - three to sprites that should hide when the player is hit but only heart three works. 
what do I need to change so it works for all three hearts?

```
public class HealthManagement : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform heartOne;
    public Transform heartTwo;
    public Transform heartThree;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() 
    {
        heartOne.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        heartTwo.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        heartThree.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }       

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() { }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D player)
    {
        if (player.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && heartThree.gameObject == true)
        {
            heartThree.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("3");
        }

        if (player.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && heartThree.gameObject == false && heartTwo.gameObject == true )
        {
            heartTwo.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("2");
        }
        if (player.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && heartThree.gameObject == false && heartTwo.gameObject == false && heartOne.gameObject == true)
        {
            heartOne.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("1");
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be the `heartThree.gameObject == true` part.

From the Unity docs:

> bool  Does the object exist?

So `heartThree.gameObject == false` will never trigger.... the objects DO exist but are inactive.

Maybe try with `heartThree.gameObject.activeSelf == false` to check for the active state

Comment: That's solved that problem thank you :) but now they both go immediately so I probably just need to implement a cool down timer.

Comment: Just do an if else rather than 3 separate if statements

Answer (score 0):

You can use the framework https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/dotween-hotween-v2-27676 from AssetStore for a beautiful animation without using a down timer. )))